# Does the result differs when writing condition in JOIN over in WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Is there a difference in terms of results in using a condition in `where` versus in `join`? In my actual query, I can put `AND "noteReads"."id" IS NULL` in `where` or in `join`. Does this matter?

First version with `AND "noteReads"."userId" = 1` in where clause:

```sql
SELECT count(distinct("notes"."id")) FROM "notes"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "noteReads" ON "notes"."id" = "noteReads"."noteId" 
  AND "noteReads"."userId" = 1 
WHERE (
  "notes"."archivedAt" IS NULL
  AND "notes"."authorId" != 1
  AND "noteReads".id IS NULL
);
```

Second version with `AND "noteReads"."userId" = 1` in join clause:

```sql
SELECT count(distinct("notes"."id")) FROM "notes"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "noteReads" ON "notes"."id" = "noteReads"."noteId" 
  AND "noteReads"."userId" = 1
  AND "noteReads"."id" IS NULL
WHERE (
  "notes"."archivedAt" IS NULL
  AND "notes"."authorId" != 1
);
```

Comment: `distinct` is not a function, it's a _<set quantifier>_ here. Simply write `count(distinct "notes"."id")` to make code clearer.

Comment: The first query is an anti join by the way (you count notes for which **not exist** a note read by user 1). Better use `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN` for a more readable query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely.

When you have the condition `"noteReads"."id" IS NULL` in the `ON` clause for a `LEFT JOIN`, then it is only considering rows where the `id` is `NULL`.  And I'm guessing that is never true.

When you have the condition in the `WHERE` clause, then if filters out *non-matching rows*.  That is *very* different.

Note:  This explanation is specific to the second table in a `LEFT JOIN` (or the first table in a `RIGHT JOIN`, although I generally recommend using `LEFT JOIN`s).

Comment: Thank you! It's super clear and it makes sense! (context: I try to fix queries generated by an ORM). I will accept your answer in 10 minutes.

Comment: Personally, I would only put `JOIN` conditions in the `JOIN` clause, or you might confuse the optimiser. In your case you appear to be only joining the rows on `"notes"."id" = "noteReads"."noteId"`. Also, you might get a faster response if you use a sub-query, but depends on your SQL server & data. With MySQL, if you have a big table with only a few matching rows, a sub-query in the `FROM` can be much much faster.

Comment: @James . . . It makes a big difference where `"noteReads"."userId" = 1` goes.  I'm pretty sure the correct logic is that this goes in the `ON` clause.

Answer (score 1):

here in this case we have to understand ,

1. the where clause is on the result set of left join. that means the records which are not matching the joining criteria will populate right table field as null and you are filtering those record which are not matching.
2. if you use the same condition in left join clause it will only match those records which are having null values because you set it as a matching criteria.